# Regex to remove a hash-parameter from the urls hash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a such url

```
 http://localhost:18314/#&t=325&r=342793184&c=408C0115-BBF9-4D1B-B02B-0CCB1D033768&r=open
```

or

```
http://localhost:18314/#&t=325&c=408C0115-BBF9-4D1B-B02B-0CCB1D033768
```

I need a javascript regex which can remove "&c=408C0115-BBF9-4D1B-B02B-0CCB1D033768" from the hash.

Comment: out of curiosity why are you putting the values in the hash? usually they would go in the querystring between `?` and `#`. not sure, but search engines etc may have problems crawling pages with such URL's

Comment: This project is not open for indexing anyway.

Comment: Voted down for not being smart enough to NOT use regex when you don't have to. >__>

Comment: I did not get it. What is the problem with using regex? Your solution does not work for me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
var url2 = url.replace(/&c=[^&]+/,'')
```

Comment: do note that the `+` operator matches one or more characters, so if the URL happened to be e.g. `.../#&c=&t=325` (blank c parameter) it wouldn't get removed. i would use `*` instead: `/&c=[^&]*/` (unless I was certain the `c` parameter will always be non-empty-string.)

Comment: Thank you dystroy!
and to you Plato. It will never be empty, but it good to know! :)